# Errors using MailChimp API adding email address to list

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to add email addresses to my mailchimp mailing list but am getting an error saying

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/######/members/" on this server.
Reference #18.1e89655f.1546511382.213522b5
```

I have just created the API key and haven't done much with MailChimp before. I think the list ID is correct, I just grabbed it from the URL of my actual list in a browser https://us9.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/members/?id=######

```
<?php

$email = '####@####.##';
$authToken = '#######################-us9';
$email_list = '######';

$postData = array(
    "email_address" => "$email", 
    "status" => "subscribed",
    "merge_fields" => array(
    "NAME"=> "",
    "PHONE"=> "")
);

$ch = curl_init('https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$email_list.'/members/');

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: apikey '.$authToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);

?>
```

Comment: There is a permission issue on the server.

Comment: Is this a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648270/access-denied-from-mailchimp-api

Comment: Contact mailchimp support, server issues can only be solved by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API list ID is not the same as the browser one. (Don't ask me why). To find out the API list ID, use the API Playground. https://developer.mailchimp.com/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I figured this out while I was looking into it but unfortunately still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I think the IP of your server is blacklisted for Mailchimp. You should contact Mailchimp and ask if the server IP is blacklisted for them.

Answer (score 0):

It was a transient error for me, which went away after a couple of minutes. If it doesn't then somehow Akamai has probably blacklisted you and you need to contact Mailchimp ([as Akamai does not handle Mailchimp specific requests directly](https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/question/0D50f00005ry2Lb/i-can-no-longer-access-mailchimp-from-my-website-ip-blocked-why?language=en_US)).

If you look in the response headers, it says `Server: AkamaiGHost`, which I assume is the proxy Mailchimp is using. Also the response is `text/html`, which does not match [Mailchimp's own documented error formats](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/#error-format)–another sign that it is the proxy blocking you and not Mailchimp itself.